# PHP form not opening in the same page

Tags: php, forms

I have a button which makes a form open on the same page.

The button is wrapped in a link as follow:

```
<a href="index.php?entry=true">
  <button type="submit">Enter now!</button>
</a>
```

The form is just below this link, everything is on the same page. The issue I have is that it does not work in IE7 and 8 and ideas? Everywhere else is fine!

Comment: why are you using button inside the anchor tag???

and why it of type submit??

Comment: that button has a specific style. I guess I could just style the anchor tag. Would that solve the issue?

Comment: What are you planning to do ? Why do you need a button inside a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to w3c you "can't" nest a button in an a tag.

If you want some redirection after pressing the button do it like this:

`<button type="button" onclick="document.location.href='example.com'">Leave this Place!</button>`

if you dont set that type you get a `<button type="submit">` by default

Comment: Hi I have removed the buttom element from inside the anchor tag and styled the a tag instead. It seems to work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`<button>` should be part of `<form>` not `<a>` so your valid markup would be

```
<form method="post" action="index.ph?entry=true">
<button type="submit">Enter now!</button>
</form>
```

EDIT: ok, so you need something looking like button. Style `<A>` using CSS (not tested, but you get the picture):

```
a:link {
 border-style: solid;
 border-width : 1px 4px 4px 1px;
 text-decoration : none;
 padding : 4px;
 border-color : #69f #00f #00f #69f;
 }
```

Comment: That link is outside the form because it has nothing to do with the form itself is just a link/button to make the form open once you click enter now on the same page.

Comment: form elements cannot really live outside a form without tricks with JavaScript. So if you want to have a link looking like a button, just use CSS and style something to look like a button.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't wrap a button inside an anchor element, it's not valid markup (according to W3C).

Use `a` or `button`; not both together.